# php on trax: passing var to view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm very new to PHP on TRAX and the site's doc(s) aren't that great... How do i pass a var (say `$monthago`) to the view?

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're looking for a PHP rails clone, you might want to try [akelos](http://www.akelos.org/). It doesn't appear that Trax is updated anymore.

Comment: Still updating it but definitely need help

Comment: We've actually been using TRAX for a couple years. At the time, it was the closest to Rails. Close enough, we've been able to slowly migrate from PHP to Rails completely, using the same Tables (ie- ActiveRecord)

Answer (score 0):

$this->VariableName = $VariableName;

so simple, I almost felt dumb asking the question :)